# How to select and click all html checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I desire to select and click **all** checkboxes in a webpage. I've tried:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button[role="checkbox"]').forEach((e)=>{
    e.click();
});
```

Also:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[aria-checked="false"]').forEach((e)=>{
    e.click();
});
```

Nothing happens, and devtool console outputs "undefined".

To reproduce you need to have an hotmail email account with messages already deleted.

In hotmail.com go to "Deleted items", there to "recover deleted items", and then a window will be opened with deleted conversations. Near to each conversation there will be a checkbox.

Comment: Undefined means you've selected wrong (and non existing data). Can you share snippet of your HTML containing said checkboxes?

Comment: `$(":checkbox").click()` ? add html mark up for clarification

Comment: Sorry, the webpage contains private information and to reproduce online one has to have a hotmail email account with many messages already been deleted. I just want to mark all checkboxes whatsoever in a webpage. These are plain and simple html checkboxes without anything custom.

Comment: @guradio this doesn't work.

Comment: without the html mark i can only guess.

Comment: @fayalikt part of a usable question is including [necessary details to recreate your error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If it's proprietary or private, then anonymize as necessary to help the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but missing a few details.  First, the query selector functions work.  Finding elements is their bread and butter.  If you're getting undefined, then your selector string is not correct.  Does your HTML implement check boxes with `<input type="checkbox">`?

Second, don't use `.click()`.  That may work, but is more work and cognitive effort for the followup/maintenance programmer.  It additionally might trigger click events (unless of course you'd like that too).  Just set the `checked` attribute:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach( (e) => e.setAttribute('checked', '') );
```

Comment: Thanks! In this case these are `button` instead `input`. Will try it in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

If your checkboxes are `inputs` you can use...

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
```

... or...

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe instead of simulate click, try to manually set `aria-checked` attribute :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[role="checkbox"]').forEach((e)=>{
    //e.click();
    e.setAttribute("aria-checked", "true")
});
```

see here : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xnwpgbk/)

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id")+" changed");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" checked="checked"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox3"/>
```