# What can cause click() method to fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have an element (a checkbox), with this HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="_f_V1 noMargin o365button" aria-labelledby="_ariaId_28" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false">
    <span class="_fc_3 owaimg checkboxImage wf-size-checkboxMultiselectSize ms-bg-color-white ms-border-color-neutralSecondaryAlt"> </span>
    <span class="_fc_4 o365buttonLabel _fc_2" id="_ariaId_28" style="display: none;"></span>
</button>
```

Note it's a button element even though it behaves like an `<input [type="checkbox"]>`.

I aim to select and click on this element with the `click()` method. The selection is correct, but the `click()` method fails.

### What I did:

```
document.querySelector('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').click();
```

Yet nothing happens - the checkbox won't be checked.

Given this (first) element is but one of a list of similar elements, I've also tried:

```
(()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('button span').forEach((e)=>{
        e.click()
    });
})();
```

Again, neither the first, nor any other checkbox is selected.

From running `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` (with their relevant selectors) in console, I get the elements I want (I don't get `undefined`), so it means my selections are correct.

Given the selections are correct, why would the `click()` method have no effect?

When I click with the mouse --- the checkbox is **checked** but when I use `click()` on the same element, it doesn't.

If you want to try to reproduce **online**, you need to have an Hotmail email account with messages that you've already deleted. If this is the case:

---

1. Go to "Deleted items".
2. Go to "recover deleted items".
3. a window will be opened with deleted conversations.
4. Near to each conversation there will be a checkbox (after mouseover). This is the element I'm having the trouble with.

Note: The mouseover just changes opacity of the checkboxes.

Comment: will you provide code snippet so i can check it ?

Comment: how about `e.setAttribute("aria-checked", "true")` instead of `e.click()`

Comment: Are you sure the element you see on the screen really is the same you attach the click event?

Comment: Dhaval, [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMqQvL) didn't show the whole code. There seem to be more HTML needed but given there isn't any efficient way to copy DOM code (at least, not one that I'm aware of), sadly I'll probably won't provide something like this even that I want...

Comment: @dann, I already tried several actions with `setAttribute()` including the exact example you gave but it didn't help.

Comment: @Teemu thus it seems directly from the DOM...

Comment: I can select the checkbox using `setAttribute` : https://jsfiddle.net/7xnwpgbk/

Comment: @fayalikt Please re-read my previous comment very carefully. You're using some template or framework, which might replace the original with some other elements, that are what you actually see. You're attaching the event to the original button element, which might not be shown, hence it is possible that you're not clicking the element you've attached the event.

Comment: @dann, it doesn't work online, sadly. There is some bias in Hotmail deleted messages window.

Comment: @Teemu I am not sure I understood correctly but even if I do, is there anything to do in this case when the element is "replaced" with a seemingly identical one?

Comment: Dear @fayalikt did you had a look at my answer (made some edits since I posted it). If it doesn't work as you want it to please leave a comment, as I have another idea... regards

Comment: BTW: what do you expect triggering an onClick event to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select and click all html checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802551/how-to-select-and-click-all-html-checkboxes)

Comment: Axel, thanks, will take a look right now. BTW, onClick? onClick event?... I don't listen to such event in this case, maybe you meant the `click()` method? I desire that it would cause the same as manual clicking --- Add a V to the checkbox.

Comment: @fayalikt thats not really the case. Out of time now I will explain a bit later (promised!). Next time if you want "ping" somebody in a commet prepend  "@" (like "@Axel") otherwise the person will not ne noticed...

Comment: han I misclicked when voting to close...  I wanted the [MCVE] one.

Comment: @fayalikt I added a new answer. Please have a look at it. I would be happy if you let me know what you think about it... regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is:

> What can cause click() method to fail?

**Then the Answer is: Kinda NOTHING!** If the [`click`-method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) is available for an HTMLElement then calling `HTMLElement.click()` can not "fail" (in that sense). What could happen is that calling click on this element will not have the desired effect/impact - which is the case for the questions author! *"just for the sake of completeness..."*

---

After deeper investigation, here is my conclusion.

1. The actual event handlers that are responsible for checking and unchecking (and all that is related to it) are callbacks "listen to" `mousedown`-events on these `button._f_V1.noMargin.o365button`-elements ([boot.worldwide.0.mouse.js:37](https://r4.res.office365.com/owa/prem/16.1946.26.2421381/scripts/boot.worldwide.0.mouse.js)); so you will not get anywhere triggering `click`-events. One may ask: "how can you say so?". I can say so because I removed ALL other event listeners first traversing up two parents and then from there on all the way down with each and every child element except for the `button` where I left the `mousedown`-eventListener. And the functionality was still intact. After removing also this last event listener the functionality was gone. So I guess: yep I can say so :)
2. My next step was to trigger a `mousedown`-event on the `button` like this:

   ```
   $('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').each(function() {
       $(this).mousedown();
   })
   ```

   But NO this doesn't work.
3. So what about hysterically triggering events on every maybe-relevant element like this:

   ```
   var $El = $('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').parent().parent();
   $El.add( $El.find('*') ).each(function() {
       $(this).mousedown().mouseup().click();
       // may be one event is cancelling the result of another one out
       // so I also tried $(this).mousedown()
   });
   ```

   NO - this also doesn't work.
4. So I came up with my last approach which didn't work either. Let’s mimic the attributes and properties from selected `button`. BTW the element that is actually responsible for making the "pseudo checkbox" look like checked/unchecked is the first `span`-childNode of the `button`-element. So if you type in the following code in the console of your browsers devtool everything will look exactly as it was properly clicked (or mousedowned so to say):

   ```
   $('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').each(function() {
       $(this).trigger('mousedown').addClass('_f_V1 noMargin o365button _f_W1').attr('aria-checked', 'true').prop('aria-checked', true)
           .children(':first').trigger('mousedown').addClass('_fc_3 owaimg ms-Icon--check wf-size-checkboxMultiselectSize ms-bgc-w ms-fcl-nsa-b ms-fcl-ns-b ms-border-color-neutralSecondaryAlt')
               .parent().parent().parent().trigger('mousedown').attr('aria-selected', 'true').prop('aria-selected', true)
   })
   ```

   See the screen capture below where I pastet the above snippet straight into devtools console and the "pseudo checkbox" appear as they where clicked.

   [image: Screen Caputure]

So what to do now? Ask another question! One that is much more specific. Something like: **"How to [recover|deepDelete] all deleted messages in hotmail.com"** Because this is what the intent of the question actually is - not sure about it but I guess.

---

Just want to emphasize this once more: In general the code from OP and also the code in this answer works. It does right, so to say. But it’s not able to achieve what the author wants to achieve.

---

Additionally here is a proof that the OPs code is actually working:

```js
document.querySelector('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').addEventListener(
  'click', function() { console.log('jepp') }
);

document.querySelector('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').click();
// BTW: yep HTMLElement.click() returns undefined
console.log(
  'yep HTMLElement.click() returns: ',
  document.querySelector('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').click()
)
```

```css
button {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="_f_V1 noMargin o365button" aria-labelledby="_ariaId_28" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false">
    <span class="_fc_3 owaimg checkboxImage wf-size-checkboxMultiselectSize ms-bg-color-white ms-border-color-neutralSecondaryAlt"> </span>
    <span class="_fc_4 o365buttonLabel _fc_2" id="_ariaId_28" style="display: none;"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Axel, much thanks. Thumbed up. Please edit and delete the 's's in the end of some examples. It's best to write examples in a singular way for shortness and it's usually enough. Regarding the last thing you wrote > [recover|deepDelete] all deleted messages in hotmail.com >, well, can you try to reexplain what you think happened there?

Comment: @fayalikt sorry, what exactly should I reexplain?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to this quote from the answer: `[recover|deepDelete] all deleted messages in hotmail.com`.

Comment: @fayalikt this is meant as a suggestion. Do you want to check the "pseudo checkboxes" (this I already answered...) or do you want to recover/deleteForever the items from deleted folder? If it's the latter then specifically ask for this. You know what I mean?

Comment: I now understood what you meant. I personally meant only for the selection of the pseudo-checkboxes (good terminology, I should have describe it that way ^__^). As far as I understood from your answer, you say it's **impossible** to check these pseudo-checkboxes in the `click()` or `setAttribute()` methods? Right? Maybe I missed a third way.

Comment: Yes @fayalikt, if you just want to "select" (or better to say: make them look like checked), then I already gave you an adequate answer. Please have a look at "point 4." of my explanations. If you copy the given snippet and paste it straight forward to devtools console, all pseudo checkboxes will appear as they where clicked but without the corresponding functionality. Updated my answer with a screen capture...

Comment: So, dear Axel, I've marked the answer is correct. If I understand point 4 correctly, what you did was to changed everything in the (first) `span` element to be the same as it would be when it is clicked. You gave the `span` both the classes, and attributes of the its own clicked instance?

Comment: I must say though, I still don't understand why the `click()` method didn't work... Isn't the whole point that it would be **exactly** like a manual mouse click?... O_o

Comment: @fayalikt yes you got point 4 correct. But what you described for the first `span` I also did for the `button` and for the second parent-`div` (`<div MOD><div><button MOD><span MOD>` where MOD is "class" & "aria-*"). So what about the click? Its all about [DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) (click is an DOM Mouse Event). If you manually click an DOM Element, there will be an click event fired that bubbles up the DOM tree. Now you can listen to these events by `addEventListener`.

Comment: And the callback that you "subscribed" to the event can handle the event (thats why you will often see the term event handler [function/callback] in this scope). When you call the `click` method on a HTML Element this click event will be fired just if as you had clicked with mouse - so the attached event handlers will be called.

Comment: In the case of your button-issue the functionality is not attached to the `click`-event but to the `mousedown`-event. You can see this very simply if you click the pseudo checkbox (just mousedown don't release you finger) in that moment the box will appear as selected. But at this phase the click event hasn't fired yet. The next event that gets fired is the `mouseup`-event and then comes the `click`-event (at this time the party is already over for your button-issue).

Comment: @fayalikt I'm just curious. What is your actual intention for this task. Do you really just want to have it look like if the buttons where clicked? What is this good for :) ?

Comment: This is just for learning - I tried to create a small script to mark all messages so I could click "purge" for all messages together but it didn't succeed with the `click()` method so I tried to change attributes with `setAttribute` but this also didn't help, so I tried to consult some senior frontend developers like yourself, as I'm a humble freshman. Vielen Dank für alles!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with [jQuery 
`click` method](https://api.jquery.com/click/) which will only work on jQuery collections created like:

```
jQuery( 'your whatever selector(s) here' ) // form here on you can call .click() now
```

So for your specific approach you can do:

```
jQuery('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').click();
```

as well as:

```
jQuery('button span').click();
```

---

Since jQuery `click` method does only trigger an on click event on the first DOM element of a jQuery collection you can combine it with [jQuery method `each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) as follows:

```
jQuery('._f_V1.noMargin.o365button').each(function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

as well as:

```
jQuery('button span').each(function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: Axel, I can swear I had several cases that at least `document.querySelector('something').click();` worked. Anyway, `jQuery('button span').click();` seems to work but it stops after one element. In a quick search going through some jQuery QA session I didn't find how to emulate `document.querySelectorAll` in jQuery (I know only vanilla, never worked with jQuery). How will you emulate this?

Comment: @fayalikt see my update and feel free to leave a comment if it doesn't do it for you...

Comment: @fayalikt I'm a bit out of time now - but will add some extra information for your better understanding - ok?

Comment: @Kaiido thank you very much I didn't know that! You never stop learning and will update my answer accordingly soon

Comment: Sure Axel, I'm here. Danke schon (sorry no omlauts) for everything!

Comment: Hey @fayalikt - just for the record: did my suggestion work?

Comment: Hmm, just tested both last codes directly on hotmail.com... Sadly, it doesn't do the trick. :\ There some to be some bias there that flaws natural behavior of any code I've tested so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function handelClick(){
  if(this.getAttribute("aria-checked")=="true"){
   this.setAttribute("aria-checked", "false");
  }else{
  this.setAttribute("aria-checked", "true");
 }
}
var button=document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
 button[i].addEventListener('click', handelClick);}

 goto https://jsfiddle.net/7xnwpgbk/5/
 it may help you
```

Comment: Sadly the code doesn't work in hotmail.com (they seem to implement some library that causes the unnatural behavior).