# How to check pseudo checkboxes in a loopish way, in hotmail.com recover/delete section?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

This question is for programmers using Microsoft's Hotmail service.

In the website [hotmail.com](http://hotmail.com) there is a section with messages you already deleted, so to recover or fully delete them. You can access that section this way:

1. Go to "Deleted items".
2. Go to "recover deleted items".
3. A window will be opened with deleted conversations.
4. Near to each conversation there will be a checkbox (after mouseover which changes the opacity of the checkbox to `1`).

In this section, there are multiple **pseudo** checkboxes that I couldn't target with a script containing `click()` and/or `setAttribute()`:

```
(()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('button span').forEach((e)=>{
        e.click()
    });
})();
```

The pseudo checkboxes are not `input[type="checkbox"]` elements of course (as you most probably have seen, they are `span` elements).

The Hotmail webapp is based on custom technology that makes it entirely unnatural in compared to many other websites and as of the moment I don't have enough knowledge in JavaScript, or the spare time to keep investigating this in a serious manner (we already had long discussions regarding it in [this SOF QA session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804796/what-can-cause-click-method-to-fail)). I'm not even sure that HTML has anything to with this.

A solution to check all pseudo check all pseudo checkboxes was correct but isn't enough to make the checked checkboxes to be considered "checked" by their check validation mechanism, hence, the messages cannot be recovered or deleted).

---

### Alternative approach:

It seems to me that JavaScript isn't the correct solution for this problem of checking pseudo checkboxes that wouldn't otherwise be selected in common JavaScript methods and I should take another approach from the outside.

#### My thought:

I need a way to make a mouse click anywhere on the screen whether if I do computing from Windows10, Linux (Ubuntu), or macOS. Is there any such "cross platform" way to initiate a mouse click or must I use AHk in Windows, or any other "local" scripting language for each different operating system?

My final aim is to have a script that starts when I press a certain keyboard key and does this **loop** (I will place the mouse cursor on a pseudo checkbox just before starting the loop):

1. Triggers a left mouse click event, wherever my mouse cursor is aimed at the moment.
2. Goes down say 30 pixels, in this case, to the next pseudo checkbox.
3. Does go out of the current window it works on, so it would scroll down inside the window and the cursor won't get out of the window.

---

### Notes:

1. Either way, I believe a solution must include both JavaScript and an external (non browser) automation solution. JavaScript could use me to set the opacity of the checkboxes to `1` arbitrarily and to set scrollheight to maximum, so to show all pseudo checkboxes for easy selecting with an outside mechanism that checks them and scrolls down.
2. Given the Operating system I use most frequently is Windows10, and the unlikelihood for an efficient crossplatform solution, I guess the best solution I Can have, is in [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey).
3. If you have a better approach to cope with this, please publish an answer.

Comment: This question does not seem like a good fit for SO. I cannot decide if it belongs to super user or on an elance site. You also may have an X/Y problem since you seem to investigate some means to click something but your issue might be to recover deleted emails? If so, there may be a “live”api available

Comment: Please change the title to what Alex suggested assuming this is what you want: to recover/deep delete. Hotmail deleted posts

Comment: I tried to the edit the title. Please don't think it's an easy or obvious case for me either. I do want to to investigate possible ways to cope with this and I give hotmail.com only as the only example I know for this problem.

Comment: But why would you use such a specific implementation for some general method younwant to find? If it works in hotmail, it’s not necessarily going to work in gmail

Comment: If it's a way to emulate a natural mouse click on the pseudo checkboxes, it will work everywhere (even on true checkboxes) though because there isn't any efficient way I know of to check Microsoft's pseudo checkboxes, I need something so general as to emulate true mouse clicks outside of JavaScript with maybe AHk or another, cross platform external solution (alongside JavaScript manipulations I will have to do as well).